# Why mysql-connector returns eof row first when the SQL statement arguments are passed by reference?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

When the arguments for a SQL statement in a function are passed by when calling the function, mysql-connector returns eof first and then 'columns' row. This results in displaying empty result by processing the eof row first.

The following code works and returns a row. However ***if I replace data = ('ABC','XYZ') with data = (symbol,exchangetr)*** as we are passing the values by calling the function,the code does not work and returns an empty tuple.

```
import mysql.connector
import datetime

def connectToDB():
    config = {
        'user': '',
        'password': '',
        'host': '',
        'raise_on_warnings': True,
        'port':,
        'database': '',
    }
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
    print('connection successful')
    return cnx


def closeConnToDB(cnx):
    cnx.close()
    print('close connection successful')

cnx = connectToDB()
cnx.get_warnings = True
dBcursor = cnx.cursor()


def getInstrumentToken(symbol, exchangetr):
    query = "SELECT abc FROM xyz WHERE x = %s and y = %s"
    ***data = ('ABC','XYZ')***
    dBcursor.execute(query, data)
    print(dBcursor.fetchwarnings())
    print(dBcursor.fetchall())
    dBcursor.close()
    closeConnToDB(cnx)
    return

getInstrumentToken('ABC', 'XYZ')
```

Upon debugging the code, I have realized that the following gets returns from MYSQL server when I pass the arguments by calling the function.

```
{'eof': {'warning_count': 0, 'status_flag': 33}, 'columns': [('instr_token', 3, None, None, None, None, 0, 4097)]}
```

But when I directly pass arguments by hardcoding the data variable, I get the following from the MYSQL server.

```
{'columns': [('instr_token', 3, None, None, None, None, 0, 4097)], 'eof': {'warning_count': 0, 'status_flag': 33}}
```

By first processing the EOF row, mysql-connector is incorrectly resulting in zero rows getting displayed. I am a newbie to python and it seems there are some subtle issues with mysql-connector. What is the problem with my code? Can't we pass arguments to a SQL statements from outside? Please help.